# Parity on Windows 64bit Questions

Tags: mining, synchronization, windows, parity

Today I downloaded Parity for Windows.
Start it with **parity --author 0x9999999999999  --rpc --rpcaddr 192.x.x.1 --rpcport 8545**.

Then I have started ethminer  **ethminer -G -F 192.x.x.1:8545**

When I go to parity's interface I see the best block sync with etherstats, but no commit on next block. Why?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--author` requires an argument: you must tell it *what the payout address is*.

e.g. `parity --author 0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890 --rpc --rpcaddr 192.x.x.1 --rpcport 8545`

For what it's worth, Parity enables RPC by default on 8545 - you only need:

`parity --author 0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890 --rpcaddr 192.x.x.1`

Comment: **--author**  was followed by my account. I removed --rpc but no commit on next block . How do I know if I'm mining correctly. Which Feedback?

Comment: Please rephrase the original question with complete information (i.e. don't skip CLI arguments and explain thoroughly what you mean by "but no commit on next block"). Alternatively join the Gitter chatroom and get an interactive diagnosis.

Comment: ok now I edit the question whit an account's example, and now?

Comment: i have no idea what you mean by "but no commit on next block".

Comment: When you mine on geth, in console,  you have the commit work on current mining block.

Comment: see the picture https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/6788/syn-flooding-on-port-30303-geth

Comment: parity doesn't give such an output message (i can consider adding it if you feel it's very useful). you should see a message in `ethminer` saying that there's a new work package - that indicates that parity has moved on to the new block.

Comment: Thank you. I know that my English sucks, I'm glad we understand each other . When I had network problems that message was the only output that can make me understand the problem (ethminer always gave new work package ) . To better understand, which ethminer's feedback I have to look to understand that I'm mining properly? Tks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41677/discussion-between-underdog-and-gav).